# Comparing/Switching Selected JButtons within a 2D Array

Tags: java, swing, jframe, comparison, jbutton

Similar questions to my own have been asked, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to proceed. I really have a poor grasp of some of the more subtle nuances of java, so I apologize if anything isn't clear.

Say for example I wanted to compare one JButton within a 2D array with another. To be more specific, all of these JButton's would be stores within a 2D array and displayed in grid format. All of the buttons would have the same action listener that, upon the button being pressed, calls the setselected() method.

How would I go about comparing one of these selected JButton's with another selected JButton within the same array? And upon doing so, how could I swap the positions or more specifically, the icons of said buttons.

Below, I've included some example code and my own attempt on the subject. I understand that I can use .getSource() to grab a JButton object itself, but would this not only allow me to capture 1 selected button at a time. This is all considering the use of the same actionlistner code for each button, but a secular listener for each button.

The code below sets every icon to 1 of 7 randomly generated image icons. A frame is generated within secular main class. Upon being pressed or "selected" the image icons change to a selected iteration of the same image.

EDIT: Based on Ameer's suggestion, I've run into several nullpointer exceptions that are caused by my actionPerformed method. Is this as a result to my button array not being filled with button objects at this point, or am I simply presuming something within my code?

```
  public class SButtonGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener   {

    public static ImageIcon[] icons={

    new ImageIcon("img1.png"),
    new ImageIcon("img2.png"),
    new ImageIcon("img3.png"),
    new ImageIcon("img4.png"),

    new ImageIcon("img5.png"),

    new ImageIcon("img6.png"),
    new ImageIcon("img7.png"),

    };


    public static ImageIcon[] selectedIcons={

    new ImageIcon("simg1.png"),
    new ImageIcon("simg2.png"),
    new ImageIcon("simg3.png"),
    new ImageIcon("simg4.png"),

    new ImageIcon("simg5.png"),

    new ImageIcon("simg6.png"),
    new ImageIcon("simg7.png"),
    }; 





   int rowNum=0;
   int colNum=0;
   JButton[][] Buttons; 

   boolean swaptf=false;
   JButton CButton; // Selected button "holder". Doesn't accomplish anything I think it            should






    public SButtonGame(String title) {

    //Constructs frame
    super(title);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null)
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(578,634);









    int colLoc=10;
    int rowLoc=10;  
    this.colNum=0;
    this.rowNum=0;


    for(int r=0; r<8; r++)
    {

    this.Buttons= new JButton[9][9];

    this.rowNum++;

    for(int c=0; c<8; c++)
    {

    ActionListener listner = new ActionListener(){

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton)
    {




    ((JButton) e.getSource()).setSelected(true);

    CButton=(JButton)e.getSource();





    }

    }    


    };







    int ranImg;

    ranImg=0+(int)(Math.random()*7);
    int sranImg=ranImg;


    this.Buttons[this.colNum][this.rowNum]= new JButton(icons[ranImg]);
    this.Buttons[this.colNum][this.rowNum].setSelectedIcon(selectedIcons[sranImg]);
    this.Buttons[this.colNum][this.rowNum].addActionListener(listner);
    this.Buttons[this.colNum][this.rowNum].setSize(59,59);
    this.Buttons[this.colNum][this.rowNum].setLocation(rowLoc,colLoc);
    rowLoc=rowLoc+69;

    this.Buttons[this.colNum][this.rowNum].setVisible(true);

    this.Buttons[this.colNum]  [this.rowNum].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    add(this.Buttons[this.colNum][this.rowNum]);


    }
    this.colNum++;
    colLoc=colLoc+69;    
    rowLoc=10;
    } 




    JButton Newgame;
    Newgame= new JButton("NewGame");
    Newgame.setSize(100, 30);
    Newgame.setLocation(350, 560);
    Newgame.setVisible(true);
    add(Newgame);



    JButton Quit;
    Quit= new JButton("Quit");
    Quit.setSize(60, 30);
    Quit.setLocation(480, 560);
    Quit.setVisible(true);
    add(Quit);





    New.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    //dispose of current frame and generates a new one;

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

    dispose();
    SButtonGame Frame;
    Frame = new SButtonGame("ShinyButtons");

    Frame.setVisible(true);  

    }


    });
    Quit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)

    {


    dispose();


    }





    });

    }


 @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

                if(ae.getSource() instanceof JButton){

                    JButton sButton;
                   int rindex=0;
                   int cindex=0;

                    ((JButton) ae.getSource()).setSelected(true);

                   sButton=(JButton)ae.getSource();




                   if(SButtonGame.this.Buttons[(int)sButton.getClientProperty("rownum")][(int)sButton.getClientProperty("colnum")].isEnabled()==true){





                   }



                }



            }    







    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

    SButtonGame Frame;
    Frame = new SButtonGame("ButtonsGame");

    Frame.setVisible(true);




    }

    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Inside actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) method, you can access the 2D array of buttons by using **SButtonGame.this.Buttons** (ideally variable name should be buttons starting with small b).

You can then compare the clicked button with the buttons from array and do rest of your stuff.